# Quick Edit SharePoint Online Form Library

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-on-prem, quick-edit, form-library

I have a form library in SharePoint Online, and would like to be able to use Quick Edit to update multiple items at a time.  I have quick edit turned on, and am able to switch to that view.  However, all of the fields are greyed out and cannot be modified.  Are you able to use quick edit with form libraries that use InfoPath?
[image]

Comment: Does your InfoPath contain cascaded lookup functions?

Comment: It has one lookup field, but it's not a cascading lookup.  The form is pretty basic.  It has a lot of fields, but they're mostly single line of text, with the one lookup from another list on the site.  Will that prevent the list from using quick edit?

Answer (score 0):

The InfoFath form implementation for a List/Library does not have any relation with Quick Edit functionality.
Since you have already enabled Quick edit so you can simply edit fields properties similar to an excel file.

Regarding grey-out fields, you can verify if the field type is not "Calculated Field". Also, As I can see from the screen shot, Date field is not showing date-picker So you can try doing this in Internet Explorer browser.

Comment: I am unable to edit any field in quick edit.  I just used the date field as an example.  Most of the fields are simple "single line of text" fields.  Also, I am using Internet Explorer browser, so that shouldn't have anything to do with it.